Is there any chance this expression returns UNKNOWN?
Given that PostgreSQL gives no guarantees as to the order in which operands are evaluated, could this expression return UNKNOWN if the last condition is evaluated before the middle one?
"TradeOffer".status = 'Pending' AND
"TradeOffer".expiration_date IS NOT NULL AND
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > "TradeOffer".expiration_date


You should look at Operator Precedence.

Because the expressions don't have side effects, the order of evaluation does not affect the result. The only way for the full expression to return NULL is if "TradeOffer".status is NULL, in which case the result will be either NULL or FALSE. Since the DDL for TradeOffer wasn't provided, we don't know what constraints might exist.

No, because select false and null; returns false.
Or, in the where, select 1 where false and null; returns nothing (the where condition is still false)

would the parser not check all column if they exist?

@nbk I'm not sure to understand your question/comment... in the OP post, the columns do exist (but some values could be null). One can write queries with constants (as in my example), functions etc, and the output of such function is not evaluated in advance. However the logic with boolean and nulls remains the same, no matter where the boolean/null comes from.

You are correct, I was under the wrong impression that it would return NULL/UNKNOWN.

Youu could rewrite your query, to make it deterministic again
But this would only yield a Full table scan
create table "TradeOffer"(
status Text,
  expiration_date timestamp
);


CREATE TABLE


INSERT INTO  "TradeOffer" VALUES('1', NULL)


INSERT 0 1


SELECT * FROM "TradeOffer" WHERE
"TradeOffer".status = 'Pending' AND
CASE WHEN "TradeOffer".expiration_date IS NOT NULL THEN
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > "TradeOffer".expiration_date
  ELSE FALSE
END




status
expiration_date




SELECT 0


fiddle
Another solution which uses Heap index scan
create table "TradeOffer"(
status Text,
  expiration_date timestamp
);


CREATE TABLE


CREATE INDEX index1_id 
  ON "TradeOffer" USING btree (expiration_date ,status ) ;


CREATE INDEX


INSERT INTO  "TradeOffer" VALUES('1', NULL)


INSERT 0 1


EXPLAIN 
  SELECT t1.* FROM "TradeOffer" t1 JOIN "TradeOffer" t2 
  ON t1.expiration_date = t2.expiration_date 
  and t1.expiration_date IS NOt NULL 
  AND t1.status = 'Pending'
  WHERE
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > t1.expiration_date





QUERY PLAN




Nested Loop  (cost=13.33..39.97 rows=12 width=40)


->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "TradeOffer" t1  (cost=9.13..14.48 rows=2 width=40)


Recheck Cond: ((expiration_date IS NOT NULL) AND (status = 'Pending'::text))


Filter: (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > expiration_date)


->  Bitmap Index Scan on index1_id  (cost=0.00..9.13 rows=2 width=0)


Index Cond: ((expiration_date IS NOT NULL) AND (expiration_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND (status = 'Pending'::text))


->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "TradeOffer" t2  (cost=4.20..12.68 rows=6 width=8)


Recheck Cond: (t1.expiration_date = expiration_date)


->  Bitmap Index Scan on index1_id  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=6 width=0)


Index Cond: (expiration_date = t1.expiration_date)




EXPLAIN


fiddle

Be careful: Because of the CASE construction, this query can't use an index on the expiration_date column.

it is still better tnan having an underterministig query that would result in wrong ansewers.

Ohh this is helpful, thank you!
